# Boolean Algebra - Why is not(True and False) True?

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-algebra

I'm doing the book "learn python the hard way". At exercise 27 (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex27.html) it starts with boolean algebra.

So my question is:
why is `not(True and False)` True?

How I understood it, it should be the same thing as `False and True`.

Comment: `~(A . B) = ~A + ~B` - this is [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). So `not(True and False)` resolves to `not(True) or not(False)` which is `False or True` which is `True`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your interpretation is incorrect, see the [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws); specifically *the negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations*.

`not (True and False)` (*a negation of a conjunction* == `not(a and b)`) is the equivalent of `False or True` (*a disjunction of the negations* == `(not a) or (not b)`); note the switch from `and` to `or`!

You can also work out the steps:

- `not(True and False)`

  - work out the part in parentheses first, `True and False` -> `False`
- substitute that outcome back into the expression: `not(False)` -> `True`.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify last paragraph a bit, how you start evalution from within brackets and so on. To be honest it is presented in a bit unreadable style.

Answer (score 8):

`not (True and False)` simplifies first to `not (False)`, which then further simplifies to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), which states that (informally):

> "not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"
>
> also, "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".

So in your case `not(True and False)` is the same as `not(True) or not(False)` which is the same as `False or True` which is `True`

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this step by step:

`(True and False)` evaluates to `(False)`

`not (False)` evaluates to `True`

Easy enough :)

Answer (score 0):

By order of operations, what is inside the parenthesis is solved first, look at it this way with variables:

```
a == True and False == False

not(True and False) == not(a) == not(False) == True
```

What you were thinking of was:

```
not(True) and not(False)
```

Which would indeed be False because:

```
a == not(True) == False
b == not(False) == True

not(True) and not(False) == a and b == False and True == False
```